# What program has this icon?

Tags: icons

I noticed a screenshot that included this icon in the sidebar, does anyone know what it's from? It looks cool!

[image: Mystery Icon]

Looks vaguely reminiscient of Chrome but different enough that it could be a coincidence. I've tried putting it into a google image search but without any luck.

Original source was this [Ubuntu help page on unity launchers.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles#Adding_shortcuts_to_a_launcher) which includes the original, larger screenshot.

For context, it's not important, I'm just curious.

Comment: it better to ask the author of wiki "Vadim Peretokin"

Comment: Maybe it's a custom icon. Can you post the original screenshot?

Comment: All I've got is the page linked in the question: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles#Adding_shortcuts_to_a_launcher I know no more about it. It's a Mystery! (And yes, it could be a custom icon).

Comment: I went to the website and seems that, it only works on mac so I really don't understand why the hell ubuntu featured a software that doesn't work on Linux. Anyhow, I think this question should be closed, the software doesn't work on ubuntu so this is not an ubuntu question and just because an icon looks cool doesn't that a good question, that what I think but I won't be voting your question down or anything, I just flagged it, because I think it really should be closed

Comment: you just wasted 50 pts  bounty on something that's not important, you can open 2 more 50 pts bounty, if you encounter real problems and you need bounties, you might run out of rep and be really sorry for opening a bounty for a silly icon, and it won't work on your ubuntu anyway. just saying - cant flag it now it has a bounty, will flag it when it expires

Comment: @Fischer Is rep that important to you? I "spent" some little digital numbers, learnt something interesting and it made me smile. I think I won :) You're right that the answers show that it's not an Ubuntu app, but the /question/ didn't know that. However I don't mind if this gets closed.

Comment: I don't blame you, I blame ubuntu for featuring a software that doesn't work on Linux and I don't care about rep, nothing but digits but you didn't have to open a bounty for an icon either. Although I do understand why you did it, you thought that this software should be cool since it's featured on ubuntu's website, turned out it's a prank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that this is from GreekDDL Downloader.

I can provide some insight on what is happening as I am Greek myself and I knew the site that published that program.

So, greekddl.com used to be a very (**very**) popular Greek site (like ThePirateBay for Greeks) for pirating all kinds of stuff. Except from the illegal programs, movies etc. it also had almost every freeware's program new versions uploaded there. It was a very easy way to keep track of the new versions of programs.

It also had a very nice forum, the best Greek forum ever, in my opinion.

So, if I recall correctly, somebody begun reporting to Rapidshare and other file sharing sites about the pirate links available to those hosts. The corresponding hosts begun removing those links in order to avoid any copyright claims, I suppose.

Then GreekDDL hired a programmer to make a program based on JDownloader in order to download indirectly the links from the site. Basically you clicked on a button on the site and the links were added directly to your download section of the program.

Of course, the links could still be obtained from programs like Wireshark, but the reporters weren't so into tech and the reports stopped.

Eventually greekddl.com closed and became a news site that wasn't updated at all. Now it seems to be offline.

So,  you won't be able to use that program but I doubt you would want to, because it was used directly for piracy.

PS: I was the one created the article you provided with your link, so the screenshot must be from my PC when greekddl was still up. Blame me for piracy :( You cannot prove anything :D Jokes aside, I was curious to see if I could still get that links through sniffing.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. It's a shame its not a useful app (or even an app that still exists) as it is a cool looking icon.

Comment: @AndrewM Yes, the icon is beautiful and your question inspired me to look for the answer. I acted like you but I was really able to make Google showing a good image search result (the site I posted in my answer) only after I resized the icon to the standard size. Yours was a bit less. That's why you did not find it at the first place.

Comment: @Ruslan :) Yup, it is beautiful. Maybe the icon could be open sourced a recycled for another application? PS - thanks, your answer was faster and correct, but this answer from hakermania got the bounty for the extra details.

Comment: btw this icon was the logo of the site itself.

Answer (score 3):

This is the icon of the application called `GreekDDL Downloader` http://www.iboostup.com/app/cz.vity.freerapid.core.mainapp

Comment: I Used Google to Make him search me for what this image, but, it Seems in your link that this is a MacOS Application, AFAIK we are talking about ubuntu?

Comment: @Yousef's I just answer the question, the name of the program owning this icon I delivered. Why it is at the picture - it's the different question, right?